# Change font-family in CalendarView Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, calendarview

Is there way to change font-family in standart CalendarView in Android Studio?
I tried to make a style, but it works only for font color after build. In preview window calendar displays with my font-family.

[Preview image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xrjl5.png)

[After build image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VfYW.png)

Here my styles:

```
    <style name="CalendarDataTextStyle" parent="android:TextAppearance.DeviceDefault">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBackOne</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/sen_bold</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CalendarWeeksTextStyle" parent="android:TextAppearance.DeviceDefault">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorGrey</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/sen_bold</item>
    </style>
```

Here my CalendarView:

```
    <CalendarView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/calendar_back"
        android:layout_marginTop="30sp"

        android:dateTextAppearance="@style/CalendarDataTextStyle"
        android:weekDayTextAppearance="@style/CalendarWeeksTextStyle"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: If you found solution to this it's great but if you didn't and you want to be able to do all kind of customization I recommend creating your own calendar view. You don't have to do everything from scratch. Just go to SDK directory and follow sources\android-30\android\widget, you'll find SimpleMonthView.java (Download from SDK manager if you don't have it). Customize this view and load it inside a ViewPager2. That's it. If you don't know much about custom views don't worry. For example to change font, inside initPaints method you see mDayPaint.setTypeface, just set any typeface you want.